# solving a system of simultaneous equations with no values

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I need to get the conditions on $a_i$ for the set:
$$x_1+x_2+x_3=a_1a_2a_3$$
$$x_1+x_3+x_4=a_1a_3a_4$$
$$x_1+x_2+x_4=a_1a_2a_4$$
$$x_2+x_3+x_4=a_2a_3a_4$$

The best I get is 
$$x_1-x_4=a_2a_3(a_1-a_4)$$
and 5 other combinations where the LHS subscript is the same for the RHS subscripts in the bracket.

How do i continue?

Comment: Add all  and subtract any one & see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
  \left(
     \begin{array}{c}
       x_{1} \\ x_{2} \\ x_{3} \\ x_{4}
     \end{array}
   \right) &=
   \left(
     \begin{array}{cccc}
       0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
       1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
       1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
       1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
     \end{array}
   \right)^{-1}
   \left(
     \begin{array}{c}
       a_{2} a_{3} a_{4} \\
       a_{1} a_{3} a_{4} \\
       a_{2} a_{2} a_{4} \\
       a_{1} a_{2} a_{3} \\
     \end{array}
   \right) \\& \\ &=
  \left(
     \begin{array}{cccc}
       -\frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
       \frac{1}{3} & -\frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
       \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & -\frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
       \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & -\frac{2}{3} \\
     \end{array}
   \right)
  \left(
     \begin{array}{c}
       a_{2} a_{3} a_{4} \\
       a_{1} a_{3} a_{4} \\
       a_{2} a_{2} a_{4} \\
       a_{1} a_{2} a_{3} \\
     \end{array}
   \right)
\end{align*}